# Convert List of strings to ints without removing 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

So I have a list of strings that I want to convert into a list of ints

['030', '031', '031', '031', '030', '031', '031', '032', '031', '032']

How should I go about this so that the new list does not remove the zeroes

I want it like this:

```
[030, 031, 031, 031, 030, 031, 031, 032, 031, 032]
```

not this:

```
[30, 31, 31, 31, 30, 31, 31, 32, 31, 32]
```

Thanks

Comment: Ints do not contain information about their digits.  They're numbers, not orthographic representations of numbers.  If you want to display them differently you can do that with string formatting, but you can't make them show up with extra zeros by default.

Comment: May I know the reason behind keeping '0'?

Comment: btw are you talking about how the int list can be *displayed*? Try this: `print("[%s]"%", ".join(s))`.

Comment: I need each int in the list to be 3 digits long so that the numbers of each int can be placed onto the end of ints in another list of tuples, eg each number from 031 would be placed onto the end of each int in another list of tuples[(233, 199, 016)] would now be [230, 193, 011]. So I need that '0' there to replace the 3 on the end of 233. I'm just trying to hide a b&w pixel value into a RGB pixel value. Not sure if that makes any sense

Comment: @DamienSullivan That's not an operation on ints, it's an operation on the digits themselves, and hence a string operation.

Comment: I'm probably just going about this the wrong way :/

Comment: @DamienSullivan See the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `int("030")` is the same as the value of `int("30")`. The leading `0` doesn't have *semantic* value when we are talking about a number - if you want to keep that leading `0`, you are no longer storing a number, but rather a representation of a number, so it needs to be a string.

The solution, if you need to use it in both ways, is to store it in the most commonly used form, and then convert it as you need it. If you mostly need the leading zero (that is, need it as a string), then simply keep it as is, and call `int()` on the values as required.

If the opposite is true, then you can use string formatting to get the number padded to the required number of digits:

```
>>> "{0:03d}".format(30)
'030'
```

If the zero padding is not consistent (that is, it's impossible to recover the formatting from the `int`), then it might be best to keep it in both forms:

```
>>> [(value, int(value)) for value in values]
[('030', 30), ('031', 31), ('031', 31), ('031', 31), ('030', 30), ('031', 31), ('031', 31), ('032', 32), ('031', 31), ('032', 32)]
```

What method is best depends entirely on the situation.

Edit: For your specific case, as in the comments, you want something like this:

```
>>> current = ("233", "199", "016")
>>> modifier = "031"
>>> ["".join(part) for part in zip(*list(zip(*current))[:-1] + [modifier])]
['230', '193', '011']
```

To break this down, you want to do an replace the third digit of each number with the relevant number in the modifier. This is done here by using `zip()` to make columns of the numbers - `list(zip(*current))` gives us `[('2', '1', '0'), ('3', '9', '1'), ('3', '9', '6')]` - we then replace the last column with the modified one, and use `zip()` again to give us rows again. We then join the individual digits back into strings.

Note in 2.x, `zip()` gives a list, so you don't need to wrap the call in `list()`. In 3.x, you get a generator.

Comment: `030` is octal in Python2. In Python3 you're not even allowed to use it

Comment: @gnibbler I didn't word it clearly - I meant `int("030")` is the same as `int("30")`.

Comment: Jut for fun I did a numeric version. I thought the str version would look less complicated than this though.

Comment: @gnibbler I'm sure that there is a more elegant version - it'd probably be best to split it up a little, rather than doing it all in one line.

Comment: I just added a str version to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with numbers, no need to covert to str

```
>>> def f(rgb, bw):
...  return [x // 10 * 10 + bw * 10 ** i // 100 % 10 for i, x in enumerate(rgb)]
... 
>>> f((233, 199, 016), 31)
[230, 193, 11]
```

Here is a version that uses strings

```
>>> def f(rgb, bw):
...  return [s[:2] + c for s, c in zip(rgb, bw)]
... 
>>> f(("233", "199", "016"), "031")
['230', '193', '011']
```

Comment: Note in 3.x, you will need to wrap `zip()` in `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class MyNum(int):
    def __init__(self,s):
        self=int(s)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{:03d}'.format(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{:03d}'.format(self)    

li=[MyNum(i) for i in ('030','031','032')]     
n=li[0]
print li,n*2,n/3.5
```

Prints:

```
[030, 031, 032] 60 8.57142857143
```

Comment: If you see the asker's comment, the actual problem isn't how the values are represented, it's that the asker actually wants to perform an operation on the digits of the values, not as numbers.